# Can I do eigenfaces with 32bit and numpy?

Tags: numpy

I am currently trying to implement eigenfaces with numpy, but it seems to struggle with my 32bit Linux system (I use 32bit because of the formerly bad support for flash and java in 64bit, my processor is 64bit…), because when trying to multiply two vectors to get a matrix (vector * transposed vector) numpy gives me

```
ValueError: broadcast dimensions too large.
```

I read that this is due to too little memory and could be solved with 64bit. Is there some way to circumvent this? The matrix would be 528000*528000 elements. According to my paper this big matrix is needed for the covariance matrix (suming up all these huge matrices and then dividing it by the number of matrices).

My piece of code looks like this (I do not understand why numpy gives me a matrix anyway, because for my matrix knowledge it looks the wrong way round (horizontal*vertical), but it worked with examples of smaller size):

```
tmp = []
for face in faces: # just an array of all face vectors (len = 528000)
    diff = np.subtract(averageFace, face)
    diff = np.asmatrix(diff)
    tmp.append(np.multiply(diff, np.transpose(diff)))
C = np.divide(np.sum(tmp, axis=0), len(tmp))
```

Comment: What is the mathematical operation that you are trying to do? A 528000*528000 matrix of single precision floats takes 1 terabyte of memory, which you probably don't have, so it would not work even on 64 bit. So probably you do not actually want form such a matrix, but from the above description it is difficult to figure out what you are trying to do.

Comment: because my explanation skills are so bad. I have a vector with 528000 dimensions (each pixel is a dimension as I understood it). Now I need to create a matrix with `vector * vector^T` (where T stands for the transposed version of the vector), which should result in a matrix. However, they usually say that eigenface is fast and simple :/ So maybe I got something wrong. Formula is: http://www.pages.drexel.edu/~sis26/Eigenface%20Tutorial_files/image012.gif via http://www.pages.drexel.edu/~sis26/Eigenface%20Tutorial.htm where Phi is the vector.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As `pv` already elaborated, it's not really practically feasible to try to produce such huge covariance matrix.

But please note that eigenvectors (explained in your [drexel](http://www.pages.drexel.edu/~sis26/Eigenface%20Tutorial.htm) link) of `phi* phi^T` and `phi^T* phi` are related and this is the key to make the problem more manageable. See more on this topic in [Eigenface](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eigenface).

Comment: Thanks for the wikipedia link, I will try what I can do.

Comment: @Aufziehvogel: AFAIU the `Eigenface` 'algorithm' is quite straightforward and it can be implemented just quite few lines with `numpy`. Please feel free to ask more specific questions along your exploration. Thanks